# show $\text{rank}(AB)+\text{rank}(BC)\leq \text{rank}(B)+\text{rank}(ABC)$ for matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Suppose that $F$ is a field and $A\in M_{m\times k}(F)$, $B\in M_{k\times p}(F)$ and $C\in M_{p\times n}(F)$. Show that:
$$\text{rank}(AB)+\text{rank}(BC)\leq \text{rank}(B)+\text{rank}(ABC).$$
I tried to find the row/column space of those matrices and find a basis for them to find the rank. But I wasn't seccessful. Also I tried to find a relation between these spaces and say if they're subspaces of each other, but this also couldn't help me.

Any helps or hints are so much appreciated!

Comment: Frobenius rank inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$rank(B)-rank(AB)=dim (\ker\hat{A} \cap Im \hat{B})$$
$$rank(BC)-rank(ABC)=dim (\ker\hat{A} \cap Im \hat{B}\hat{C})$$

Comment: Can you explain where do this equations come from, please? Also what do you mean by putting a hat above the matrices?